# read ECONNRESET error occurs in nextjs geinitialProps when sending get request to api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, next.js

This error occured in next.js app when i send a get request using axios in getInitialPros of _app.js file.

```
 if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    // user = await checkAuth(ctx);

    // const token = ctx.req.headers.cookie;

    console.log("TOKEN", ctx.req.headers);

    if (ctx.req && ctx.req.headers.cookie) {
      try {
        res = await axiosClient("get", { cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie }).get(
          "/auth/currentuser"
        );

        user = res.data;
        console.log("USER IN SERVER SIDE", user);
        ctx.store.dispatch(setAuthenticatedUser(res.data));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("ERROR in APP", err);
        // console.log("USER FOUND IN APP.JS", res.data);
        ctx.store.dispatch(removeAuthenticatedUser());
      }
    }
  } else {
    try {
      res = await axiosClient("get").get("/auth/currentuser");

      user = res.data;
      // await checkAuth(ctx);

      // await checkAuth(ctx,)
      console.log("IN CLIENT", res.data);
    } catch (err) {}
  }
```

this error occurred when the page is refreshed but it only occurs on server side, not in client side.

```
ERROR in APP Error: read ECONNRESET
        at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27) {
      errno: 'ECONNRESET',
      code: 'ECONNRESET',
      syscall: 'read',
      config: {
        url: '/auth/currentuser',
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          cookie: 'token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI1ZjNhYTJlMmQxN2YxMzAxYTA0NGUxYTIiLCJpYXQiOjE1OTgyODUyMDMsImV4cCI6MTU5ODI4ODgwM30.qtaW-D9P6tJHzL1uHZs3wlzF39UPVkPTLEieuqaVEJY',
          'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.2'
        },
        baseURL: 'https://tatkaladda.com/api/',
        transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
        transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
        timeout: 0,
        adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        maxContentLength: -1,
        validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
        data: undefined
      },
```

this error only occurred in production app not in development mode.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm seeing the same thing in production with getInitialProps.

Comment: no, I don't find any solutions yet. I am using client-side rendering on pages where i am using getInitialProps.

Comment: Any solution @RajneeshChaurasia? I've just started getting this since upgrading to Next 11.

Comment: no, I don't find any solutions yet. It's only happening on the production server, not on a local development server.

Comment: did anyone find the solution????

Answer (score 0):

> Node.js is not aware of any baseURL. Your browser is. So on the server side you have to provide the full path, on the client side when using relative links they're relative to the base url, eg https://example.com
> *By: Tim Neutkens - Co-author of Next.js and MDX*

One of the suggested workaround is to use `full path` in the `getInitialProps` when using axios. In your case change this:

```
res = await axiosClient("get").get("/auth/currentuser");
```

to

```
res = await axiosClient("get").get("http://localhost:3000/auth/currentuser"); 
//or use external domian if you not on localhost i.e. https:api.example.com/auth/currentuser
```

If still this does not work, use axios API and set `full path` on `baseUrl` as follow:

```
// axios call
await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://abc.herokuapp.com/api/' //or baseURL: 'http://abc.herokuapp.com/api/'
)}
```

Have time! kindly read this, it might help: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/5009

#### UPDATE

Also you can try to construct your baseURL from `getInitialProps context`

```
async getInitialProps({ req }) {
    const protocol = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || 'http'
    const baseUrl = req ? `${protocol}://${req.headers.host}` : ''

    const res = await fetch(baseUrl + '/api/recent/1')
    ...
}
```

Comment: it still not working

Comment: My bad, have you tried the update to construct the url/baseurl from `getInitialProps context`

Comment: I have resolved the issue, actually, I am running the nextjs app in a container on digitalocean platform. So it was an issue related to the digitalocean platform.

Comment: Would you kindly tell us briefly what was the issue on digitalocean and how you solved it. We can then add the solution and mark this is an answer to your question.

Comment: https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/blob/master/docs/controllers/services/examples/README.md#accessing-pods-over-a-managed-load-balancer-from-inside-the-cluster

here is the solution for this issue.

Comment: Yes, in K8s you need special types of pods called `services` to enable you communicate with pods internally and externally. Happy you found the answer. I think you can add an answer to your question and accept it. Don't forget to mention the environment (i.e k8s, digitalocean,etc) you are working in.